# prove that the board contains a nontrivial rectangle whose 4 corner squares are all black or all red??

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

the question is, A 3 x 7 rectangle is divided into 21 squares each of which is coloured red or black. prove that the board contains a nontrivial rectangle (not 1 x k or k) whose 4 corner squares are all black or all red

I assume this is related to pigeon hole hypothesis??
I usually panic when I get this type of problem.. I have no idea how to solve this problem.. Even though this is just a practice question, it might be on the quiz next week, so I need to understand step by step how to solve this problem.. Anyone can give me with step by step explanations?? Thanks a lot

Comment: Are you familiar with the proof of van der Waerden's theorem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**.  See if you can explain why the following statements are true.  (I assume the rectangle has $3$ rows and $7$ columns, if not then swap rows and columns in the following.)

- The rectangle must include four columns, each having two or more squares of the same colour.  Call this the "majority" colour.
- Of these four columns, there must be two which have the majority colour in the same two places.
- Therefore, there is a rectangle whose four corners are the majority colour.

Comment: Very cool use of Pigeonhole. Is $3 \times 7$ the smallest rectangle that guarantees a sub-rectangle with four corners of the same color? I think so. I wonder if there are any ways to generalize this ... Obviously if a big rectangle has a $3 \times 7$ inside it then it will have a four-corners-same-color sub-rectangle. Also obvious is that it is never guaranteed for $2 \times n$ or $n \times 2$ rectangles ...

Comment: @Zubin Obviously a $2\times n$ rectangle can have a red first row and a black second row, and here is a $3\times 6$ rectangle with no monochromatic sub-rectangle: $$\begin{matrix}\square&\blacksquare&\blacksquare& \square&\square&\blacksquare\\
\blacksquare&\square&\blacksquare& \square&\blacksquare&\square\\ \blacksquare&\blacksquare&\square& \blacksquare&\square&\square\end{matrix}$$